Generating parameterized SQL statements with Sequelize for SQL Server
I am working with Sequelize on a SQL Server database, and I'm encountering some challenges with how Sequelize generates SQL statements for querying.
Question: is there any way to configure Sequelize to generate parameterized SQL statements like this for SQL Server? I'm looking for a solution to optimize performance and improve query security by avoiding directly embedding values into SQL statements.
Here's a sample of the Sequelize model I'm using for credentialed_facilities:
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
    const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
    const credentialedFacilities = sequelizeClient.define('credentialed_facilities', 
               { id: { primaryKey: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true }, 
                 userId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, field: 'user_id'},
                 facilityId: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, field: 'facility_id' },
                 credentialPage: { type: DataTypes.STRING(500), field: 'credential_page'} },
              { hooks: {beforeCount(options) {options.raw = true;}}});

credentialedFacilities.associate = function (models) 
{   
    credentialedFacilities.belongsTo(models.users, { foreignKey: 'userId' });   
    credentialedFacilities.belongsTo(models.facilities, { foreignKey: 'facilityId' }); };  
    return credentialedFacilities;
}

Currently, when I use
credentialedFacilities.findAll({ where: { userId: 93 } }),

Sequelize generates the following SQL statement:
EXEC sp_executesql
N'SELECT [credentialed_facilities].[id],
[credentialed_facilities].[credential_page] AS [credentialPage], [facility].[name] AS [facility.name],
[facility].[id] AS [facility.id] FROM [credentialed_facilities] AS [credentialed_facilities] LEFT OUTER JOIN [facilities] AS [facility] ON [credentialed_facilities].[facility_id] = 
[facility].[id] 
WHERE [credentialed_facilities].[user_id] = 93;

But I'd prefer a parameterized query for security and efficiency, similar to this format:
EXEC sp_executesql
N'SELECT [credentialed_facilities].[id], [credentialed_facilities].[credential_page] AS [credentialPage], [facility].[name] AS [facility.name], [facility].[id] AS [facility.id]
FROM [credentialed_facilities] AS [credentialed_facilities]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [facilities] AS [facility]
ON [credentialed_facilities].[facility_id] = [facility].[id]
WHERE [credentialed_facilities].[user_id] = @user_id;',
N'@user_id INT',
@user_id = 93'

Is there any way to configure Sequelize to generate parameterized SQL statements like this for SQL Server?
Any insights or recommendations would be much appreciated!
Thank you!
I try to override define() from sequelize.
